# Python: exec code object within special environment

Tags: python, c

here is a code that I wanna change LD_LIBRARY_PATH to exec a code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

code='''
import os
print os.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
import wrap
'''

os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/home/dma/python'
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = '/home/dma/python'

exec code
```

The output is:

```
/home/dma/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 13, in ?
    exec code
  File "<string>", line 4, in ?
ImportError: example.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

NOTE: test.py depend on wrap.so, wrap.so depend on example.so

Is there any way to execute the code object in the special environment?

Thanks
Dma

Comment: and where is example.so located?

Comment: [dma@amd64 ~/python]$ ls
example.c  example.o  example.so  test.py  wrap.c  wrap.o  wrap.so
[dma@amd64 ~/python]$ pwd
/home/dma/python

Comment: but why is the question tagged c if you want python code?

Comment: it's about Python/C exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use popen2 to resolve this problem. It works, anyone has a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though `example.so` isn't in `/home/dma/python`.

Comment: it's in the /home/dma/python. I have checked.

Comment: I import "wrap" (will load "wrap.so" at '.'), which depend on 'example.so'